# Combo box JQuery z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Estou utilizando o combo box do http://easyautocomplete.com/. Porém estou tendo um erro que faz com que o combo fique atras do conteúdo de baixo. Estou desde ontem procurando matérias e fóruns para solucionar este problema. Já utilizei o z-index, display e position. Estou utilizando também o Framework 7. Veja a imagem abaixo, coloquei um fundo apenas para base:

[image: Combo atrás do campo abaixo]

[Código Projeto](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1gwEap5oE9wAor4Eejm3hZuUSUzGx8Cxb)

Comment: Talvez o elemento que você esteja implementando isso tenha que ser `position:relative`.

Comment: @DiegoSouza acabei sem querer conseguindo resolver. Em vez de concentrar no combo box eu coloquei o z-index da coluna "Descrição" como 0 !important. Funcionou direitinho. Tentei usar todos os position e display mas nenhum funcionou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione o position relative no elemento que deve ficar atras e sera a base para o outro, esse deve ser pai na hierarquia do html do elemento que deve ficar na frente. O elemento que deve ficar na frente deve ter position absolute, altura e largura absolutas em pixel e a propriedade z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Tive que colocar o Z-index da coluna de baixo como 0 !important